# Automatic Font-size adjustment in P or Div tag in HTML5 via JavaScript without external plugin

Tags: javascript, css, html

As the question states,
I want to have the text inside the p tag or DIV tag to be automatically adjusted,

for example I set the text font size to be 30px,
then if the div/p is big enough or even huge, the text will always be in its 30px,
on the other hand if the div/p become smaller (regardless because of width/height),
the text font size will also shrink so it can display itself 100% inside the small div/p

I have looked for solutions, but many of them requires external jQuery,

 is there any simple way or a method without external plugin to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure CSS can't do this alone. You need to use JavaScript (with or without jQuery) to get the width of the text and size that to the width of it's container.

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries. You can then set a different font size when the P or DIV is within different height and width ranges.

This may help:
http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/